# How can I escape special characters correctly in code in Markdown destined for Github pages

Tags: c#, markdown, github-pages

I have the following line of code in a block of c# code contained within a markdown file.

```
 stringBuilder.AddText( $"{comma}{p.Name} = {{" );
```

The markdown file was created in VS Code and has a .md extension.  The code block itself is correctly delineated with three backticks top and bottom.

The markdown file itself is part of a series or articles being added to a GitHub pages site.

If I understand the process correctly GitHub essentially substitutes the .md extension for .html when these files are added to a Github pages site (I'm sure there's more to it but in essence that's it).  Thus when this block comes to be added to the site there is a build exception and it suggests that the {{ are properly escaped.

If I follow the suggestion proffered;

```
stringBuilder.AddText($"{comma}{p.Name} = /\{\{/");
```

my line of code ends up looking a mess in the actual output on the page as the escape characters seem to get added to it.

Can anyone suggest the correct way to do this.